# Slick code generator with Postgres in Play Framework

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I'm new to Scala and Slick.
Trying to use code generator example from here https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example and change it to Postgres driver.
Here is my code in Build.Scala file:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import Tests._


    object myBuild extends Build {
      val slickVersion = "3.0.2"

      lazy val mainProject = Project(
        id="main",
        base=file("."),
        settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
          scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
          libraryDependencies ++= List(
            "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % slickVersion,
            "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % slickVersion,
            "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.12",
            "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41"
          ),
          slick <<= slickCodeGenTask, // register manual sbt command
          sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask // register automatic code generation on every compile, remove for only manual use
        )
      )

      // code generation task
      lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
      lazy val slickCodeGenTask =
        (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
        val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath // place generated files in sbt's managed sources folder
        val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db'" // connection info
        val jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        val slickDriver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver"
        val pkg = "dao"
        val user="postgres"
        val password="pass"
        toError(r.run("slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, user, password), s.log))
        val fname = outputDir + "/dao/Tables.scala"
        Seq(file(fname))
      }
    }
```

The only things I change were drivers and login, password. As I understand it should generate code each time I run

> activator run

but it doesn't generate any code. Also, how it can be run manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your build.sbt file:

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()
slick <<= slickCodeGenTask

lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
    val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath
    val url = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.url")
    val jdbcDriver = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.driver")
    val slickDriver = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.driver").dropRight(1)
    val pkg = "test"
    val user = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.user")
    val password = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.password")
    toError(r.run("slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, user, password), s.log))
    val fname = outputDir + s"/$pkg/Tables.scala"
    Seq(file(fname))
}
```

And run it with `activator gen-tables`